# Where is unlocked package version metadata stored?

Tags: unlocked-package, dev-hub

Suppose we created 2 versions of a unlocked package. These two versions have assigned a package version ID in the Dev Hub org and are added to the sfdx-project.json:

```
  {
  "name": "NewTestProject",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "59.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "core/Account",
      "scopeProfiles": "true",
      "versionName": "v1.0.0",
      "dependencies": [],
      "default": false,
      "package": "Account Package1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": ""
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "Account Package1": "0Ho3X000000PBJZSA4",
    "Account Package1@0.1.0-1": "04t3X000003LSseQAG",
    "Account Package1@0.1.0-2": "04t3X000003LSsjQAG"
  }
}
```

Now we can install any of these two versions into any existing org using `sf` without having it's metadata stored in our local directory:

```
sf package install --package 04t3X000003LSseQAG --target-org test@example.com -k password123 -w 1
```

Where is the metadata stored? Are we retrieving it from Dev Hub using our package version ID? If so, does it mean that deleting our Dev Hub org deletes the metadata as well? Is this technicality documented somewhere? I was unable to find.

Comment: The metadata is held in the dev hub org, though the package version ID in the install URL is enough to identify for the install/upgrade. I believe you will lose access to the package if the dev hub is deleted. I don't recall any specific documentation and base this comment on my understanding from various AMA sessions. Others may have better info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual metadata storage for packages is opaque to you as an end user: it is inside the Salesforce platform.

When you upload a package, you receive an `04t` package version id. That id uniquely points to a snapshot of the package metadata taken during the upload operation and stored by the Salesforce platform.

Performing a package install does *not* retrieve metadata (or anything else) from your Dev Hub. The Dev Hub is completely out of the loop for package consumers, who only use that artifact you uploaded into the platform. However, the Dev Hub does play a role as the owner of the package.

It's technically possible for an org that owns a package to be deleted, although it doesn't happen often. This has consequences that are somewhat unpredictable, and I quite honestly don't know what they are for an Unlocked Package (I've only see it for a managed package). Note that you can [can transfer Unlocked Packages to another Dev Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_unlocked_package_transfer.htm) if you need to.

*Note: I am a Salesforce employee, but not part of the Packaging team.*